# Find out who has hacked your gmail account

Tags: ip, gmail

I received a message from google saying they had prevented a hacking attempt.  However I then received messages from friends saying that they had received spam from my gmail account.   If you go to the security tab of gmail it lists

"Application/device sign-in attempt (prevented) London (UK)"

The email from Google also lists an IP address which I am not sure I can post here.  Is there some way to get information on whose IP address it could be? For example, if it is an office or a mobile or a home IP address?

Comment: @unhillbilly No. I find two-factor auth too inconvenient sadly.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a `whois` lookup. On linux or OSX it's a command line tool. You can also find websites that provide that functionality.

However, most certainly the attacker just used this IP as a proxy or vpn endpoint to disguise his real ip. I would say it's almost certain that this is rather another victim's IP than the one of the attacker unless he's a complete noob.

So i would advise you to be careful with that IP. You might contact the abuse email address that is usually provided within the whois lookup and advise them that you are being attacked by this IP. They may inform the owner of that IP or the may just not respond at all, as this is often the case in my experience.

hth